# NestJS microservice class validator errors showing in docker container but not in API response

Tags: typescript, docker, nestjs, microservices, nestjs-microservice

I'm trying to show errors from my class validator in NestJS.
This is actually the first time I'm using microservices and Nestjs (it's for a school project).
I'm using Docker, and the errors are sent in my 'user' microservice container, but not showing in my API response. Is there a way to show them in my API response? I don't know why it's doing that.

My `main.ts` :

```js
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    validationError: { target: false, value: false },
    exceptionFactory: (validationErrors: ValidationError[] = []) => {
      return new RpcException(validationErrors);
    },
  }));
```

This is my validation class `user.dto.ts` :

```js
import {
  IsString,
  IsEmail,
  MinLength,
  IsEnum,
  IsOptional,
} from 'class-validator';
import { EnumRole } from '@lib/types/User';

export class UserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @MinLength(6)
  password: string;

  @IsEnum(EnumRole)
  @IsOptional()
  role: EnumRole;
}
```

My `user.service.ts` :

```js
  async registerUser(userDto: UserDto) {
    
    const hashedPassword = this.auth.send(
      AuthMessage.HASH_PASSWORD,
      userDto.password,
    );

    userDto.password = await firstValueFrom(hashedPassword);
    userDto.role = EnumRole.USER;

    const user = userDto as User;

    try {
      const newUser = await this.prisma.user.create({
        data: user as UserSchema,
      });

      return formatUser(newUser) as User;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError && e.code === 'P2002') { 
        return 'Email already exists';
      }
    }
  }
```

I send this to my API :

```json
{
    "email" : "4",
    "password" : "pass"
}
```

In my container, it shows that it is actually validated :

```
\[Nest\] 89  - 11/25/2023, 8:43:55 PM   ERROR \[ExceptionsHandler\] Object:
[
  {
    "property": "email",
    "children": \[\],
    "constraints": {
      "isEmail": "email must be an email"
    }
  },
  {
    "property": "password",
    "children": \[\],
    "constraints": {
      "minLength": "password must be longer than or equal to 6 characters"
    }
  }
]
```

but my error is like this in postman :

```json
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Sorry for the big post, I just want to provide as much code as possible for you to have some context.

I just have no idea what I should do to fix it, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The `RpcException` you're sending back from the microservice is serialized to an `Error` inside the microservice gateway (the HTTP server reporting the `Internal server error`), because Nest, by default, treats plain `Error` instances as `HTTP 500`. If you want to actually return something like a 400 you'd need to catch the error from the microservice and properly translate it to an appropriate HTTP exception that Nest does understand

Comment: How could that be achieved ? Sorry I'm really new to this.

Comment: Catch the error in the gateway, assert whatever properties you need to to determine what the error should be translated to, `throw new WhateverHttpExceptionYouDeterminedItShouldBe(withWhateverPropertiesYouWantToPropogate)`